# Como fazer um "Update" duplo no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou desenvolvendo um software em PHP/HTML/MYSQL FRONT.
Estou precisando dar um Update em uma tabela porém alterando duas colunas de uma só vez.Ai vem minha dúvida na variavel $gravaprat1, pois ela nao está executando o segundo comando (ENVIAR = 1).Segue:

```
$selectsql = "select osi, entrada, vendedor, prateleira, now(), abs(DATEDIFF(now(), str_to_date(entrada,'%Y-%m-%d'))) as dias from itens;";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $selectsql);

$gravaprat1 = "update itens set prateleira = 1 where abs(DATEDIFF(now(), str_to_date(entrada,'%Y-%m-%d'))) < 30 ***(NESSA PARTE ESTOU COM DUVIDA -->)***and update itens set enviar = 1";   
$prat1sql = mysqli_query($conn, $gravaprat1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seu SQL deve ficar desta forma:

```
 update itens 
    set prateleira = 1 
       ,enviar     = 1
  where abs(DATEDIFF(now(), str_to_date(entrada,'%Y-%m-%d'))) < 30
```

Em um UPDATE você deve separar os campos por "," (Virgula), e informa-los antes da clausula `WHERE`

Comment: Obrigado Matheus, funcionou certinho.

Comment: Opa, que beleza então! Não esqueça de marcar minha resposta como aceita caso tenha te ajudado realmente, ou alguma das outras respostas!

Answer (score 4):

Olá

```
$selectsql = "select osi, entrada, vendedor, prateleira, now(), abs(DATEDIFF(now(), str_to_date(entrada,'%Y-%m-%d'))) as dias from itens;";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $selectsql);

$gravaprat1 = "update itens set prateleira = 1, enviar = 1 where abs(DATEDIFF(now(), str_to_date(entrada,'%Y-%m-%d'))) < 30";   
$prat1sql = mysqli_query($conn, $gravaprat1);
```

Comment: Obrigado Jorge, eu consegui resolver dessa forma.

Comment: Não percebo porque recebeu indicação negativa.

Comment: Também não entendi, você passou a resposta correta...